# What's wrong with this LLVM register number?

Tags: code-generation, llvm

I'm writing a compiler for a simple C-like language for a course I'm taking. This bit of code:

```
int main() {
    printInt(not(0));
    return 0;
}

int not(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        int result = 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

..I naively compile to this bitcode:

```
declare void @printInt(i32)
declare void @printDouble(double)
declare void @printString(i8*)
declare i32 @readInt()
declare double @readDouble()

define i32 @main() {
entry:
    %0 = call i32 @not(i32 0)
    call void @printInt(i32 %0)
    ret i32 0
    unreachable
}

define i32 @not(i32 %n_0) {
entry:
    %0 = icmp eq i32 %n_0, 0
    br i1 %0, label %lab0, label %lab1
lab0:
    ret i32 1
    br label %lab2
lab1:
    %result_0 = alloca i32 
    store i32 0, i32* %result_0
    %1 = load i32* %result_0
    ret i32 %1
    br label %lab2
lab2:
    unreachable
}
```

However, opt does not accept that code.

```
opt: core023.ll:25:5: error: instruction expected to be numbered '%2'
%1 = load i32* %result_0
```

Now, from what I understand of unnamed temporary registers they're supposed to be numbered sequentially starting from 0. Which is the case here. But apparently the "%1 = sub.." line should have been numbered %2. Why is that? Do any of the instructions between %0 and %1 increase the sequence number? Or maybe it's just a follow-on fault from something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In LLVM, *everything* that *can* have a name but does not is assigned a number. This also includes basic blocks. In your case

```
lab0:
    ret i32 1
    br label %lab2
```

defines two basic blocks because every [terminator instruction](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#terminators) ends a basic block. This means that, conceptually, your code is parsed as

```
lab0:
    ret i32 1
1:
    br label %lab2
```

and the next free number after that is 2.

To prevent strange behavior like this, I recommend always explicitly naming basic blocks.

Comment: Another way of interpreting the cause to the problem is that you need to avoid branching immediately after a return statement. If your language has code to guarantee that all control paths return, then it should be trivial to check whether your preceding branch has returned yet or not. In the case that it has returned, there's no need to insert the branch (br) instruction. There's some amount of state bookkeeping you'll need to do to make LLVM happy with your basic blocks.